# Delayed_jobs_sqs generates Error while reserving job: undefined class/module delayed_jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, delayed-job, amazon-sqs

I was working with delayed_jobs_active_record gem to save my delayed jobs in a MySQL database for an application on ruby on rails.

Now, I am using Amazon SQS with the gem Delayed_jobs_sqs, and I am able to put the jobs in the queue, but whenever my worker tries to solve them, I obtain this error:

```
Error while reserving job: undefined class/module Credit
```

Where Credit is the class with the method that has to be solved. This was not an issue with delayed_jobs_active_record, so, I am kind of lost here. Am I missing something? I tried a "require credit" in the delayed_job initializer, without success...

Thanks in advance!